# rpmbuild -bb SPECS/netxtream....... gives redefinition of skb_end_pointer in main

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to install a NIC driver from the rpm of Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet drivers for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.1 with kernel 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64
The

```
rpm - Uvh netxtream2-6.2.23-1.x86_64.rpm
```

command works fine But when i try

```
rpm-build -bb SPECS/netxtream
```

This gives me many redefine error saying that the variable is already defined in file /usr/src/main.h and so on

How can I resolve this or am I missing something? Do I have to uninstall the older version of the nic?

Comment: We really need to see the actual errors.

Answer (score 0):

No, uninstalling the old driver will not be the solution. You are most likely not building against the correct libraries (building kernel modules is not so straightforward).

See this guide for CentOS for the details: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules